# Attempt to read property "name" on string

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo un error al hacer un insert a una base de datos
`Attempt to read property "name" on string` y asi con todos los otros campos como `calle`, `numext`, etc. Los datos del objeto si los imprime y son los mismos insertados desde el formulario de manera asíncrona y esos mismos se almacenan en la variable `centro`.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fitness2");
$centro=$_POST["centro"];
print_r($centro);
foreach ($centro as $row) {
  $name=$row->name;
  $calle=$row->calle;
  $numExt=$row->numExt;
  $numInt=$row->numInt;
  $estado=$row->estado;
  $municipio=$row->municipio;
  $localidad=$row->localidad;
  $cp=$row->cp;
  $pais='México';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO centros 
    (nombre,calle,numext,numint,cp,colonia,municipio,estado,pais) 
    VALUES 
    ('" . $name . "','" . $calle . "','" . $numExt . "', '" . $numInt . "', 
    '" . $cp . "','" . $localidad . "','" . $municipio . "', 
    '" . $estado . "','" . $pais . "')";
    
  $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if($query){
      echo "correcto";
  } else {
      echo "incorrecto";
   }
}
?>
```

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Coloca qué imprime esta línea: `print_r($centro);`

Comment: Array
(
    [name] => sdf
    [calle] => Rio nilo
    [numExt] => 45
    [numInt] => 122
    [estado] => 2
    [municipio] => 13
    [localidad] => 729
    [cp] => 45070
    [pais] => México
)

Comment: eso imprime el objeto centro

Comment: ¿Para qué el `foreach`? Suena a que te sobra.

Comment: para recorrer el objeto y que la variable que indique cada campo sea la de row

Comment: Nota que `$row` valdrá: `sdf, Rio Nilo, 45, 122, 2, 13, 729, 45070 y México` y no tienes referencia a la clave. ¿Para qué recorrer el objeto si sabes las claves de antemano?

Comment: no hermano ,es que es parte de un proyecto de la escuela pero de verdad el maestro si dio 4 veces clases se me hace mucho

Answer (score -1):

No necesistas recorrer el array con `for`, ya que según el comentario, es un array unidimencional, así que solo basta con reemplazar los valores directamente.

```
<?php
// ...

$centro = $_POST["centro"];

$name = $centro['name'];
$calle = $centro['calle'];
$numExt = $centro['numExt'];
$numInt = $centro['numInt'];
$estado = $centro['estado'];
$municipio = $centro['municipio'];
$localidad = $centro['localidad'];
$cp = $centro['cp'];
$pais = 'México';

$sql = "INSERT INTO centros 
(nombre,calle,numext,numint,cp,colonia,municipio,estado,pais) 
VALUES 
('$name', '$calle', '$numExt', '$numInt', '$cp', '$localidad',
'$municipio', '$estado', '$pais')";

// ... Ejecutar la consulta sql
```

Comment: muchas gracias hermano ,ya lo corrijo